How Do I get a response in the schema format at the bottom of the page
I'm trying to call the api from solscan(pro) from this page: https://pro-api.solscan.io/pro-api-docs/v1.0#/. All of the regular apis work fine, but I want the data to be formatted as it is in the schemas at the bottom, for example,Token Info, but I'm not sure how to format the request.

I imagine you need to make a call like this one https://pro-api.solscan.io/pro-api-docs/v1.0#/Token/get_token_meta
